# SharePoint 2010 - Missing Webparts / Can't Edit Default Site Page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010

Users noticed yesterday that webparts were missing on the default home page.  Clicking edit generates the following message:

Sys.InvalidOperationException: Could not find updatedPanel with ID 'ctl00_panelzone'.  If it is being updated dynamically then it must be inside another UpdatePanel.

Rebooted app/web server and attempted restore using SPD but issue remains.

How can I fix error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that there was something wrong with one of the posts in a web part.  I deleted the title/description, added information back to the post and saved it.  Something with the font or being bold.....